# "Decoding time" vs. "time of decoding"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, possessives, possessive-s-vs-of, modifier-vs-of

What's the difference between "decoding time" and "time of decoding", "data compression" and "compression of data"? And why isn't it "decoding's time", but "decoding time"?

Comment: Related: [Correct naming form (with or without “of”)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22431/correct-naming-form-with-or-without-of), [Where can I find a list of ways to get rid of the preposition “of”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4802/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-ways-to-get-rid-of-the-preposition-of).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To a native American English speaker (at least to me), these have different implied meanings:

- **decoding time** - Can mean *how long the decoding process takes*, if you write "Decoding time will depend upon..." **or** *when the decoding happens*, if you write "At decoding time, ..."
- **time of decoding** - when the decoding takes place
- **data compression** - Can refer to the *process*: "Now performing data compression..."  **or** to the *degree of compression*: "90% data compression has been achieved using this method."
- **compression of data** - refers to the process.

When we create phrases of the form "(*noun*) time", we use the noun as an adjective to describe the time we'll be spending on that noun; we don't say "(*noun*'s) time", which would imply that (*noun*) was a person who owned that time.

Other examples:
Design time, compile time, run time (different from "run-time" or "runtime"), Amok time.

Comment: +1. "compression of data" could also mean "compressed data"... but not typically.

Comment: I think you'd have a hard time proving that all usages of "run time" intend a different sense than "run-time"/"runtime", but I catch your drift.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I didn't state that as well as I could have; what I meant is that **run time** usually means *when the program executes*, **runtime** usually means *the program's actual binary image or executable*, and **run-time** usually means *the time the program takes to execute*... but that the three terms do tend to get used interchangeably and to blur a bit.

Comment: As a semi-retired programmer myself I appreciate the distinction, though I personally used to avoid *run time* completely. For me, *run-time* was when the program was run, and *runtime* was how long it took. I never tried to establish whether there was a 'standard' way to distinguish between these meanings, but I don't think anyone ever picked me up on my own usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Fair 'nuff.  Did you ever use one of those variants to refer to the finished executable?  I find that one completely unnecessary ("executable" works just fine, thank you) but I see it everywhere.

Comment: Also - I don't wish to seem nit-picky - but I frankly don't believe your distinction between **data compression/compression of data* has any significant currency in standard usage. Sure, there are two different concepts. But I don't think many people would distinguish them by using these two expressions.

Comment: As for the *finished executable*, that was either the *release* or the *distributable*. I've got the vague idea some people may call it the *runtime executable*, but I think not anywhere I've worked.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I didn't mean to imply that all four phrases were current or standard; it's just that those are the four he asked about.  I for one don't use, and have rarely if ever seen, "compression of data" - but if I used it, I would use it to mean the process, and if I read it, I would understand it to mean the process.

Comment: +1 I agree in general; but I disagree about the reason why the possessive s isn't used here: it is largely an arbitrary matter, cf. *two days' time*, *a day's work*, *the sun's rays*, etc. It is just that sometimes inanimate possession is OK, and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: I'm frankly shocked that no-one has called me on the blatant Star Trek reference, by the way.

Comment: @Cerberus - I agree with you about inanimate possession, but I was specifically talking about "time".  I sat and thought (maybe not long enough!) but I couldn't think of any phrases of the form "*noun's* time" where "*noun*" was inanimate.  There are probably dozens of counterexamples, but they elude me...

Comment: @Cerberus: I agree with you the *reason* possessive s isn't used in the first place is effectively "arbitrary". But I agree with @MT_Head's explanation of why there's nothing actually *wrong* with the form we do use.

Comment: I'm crestfallen to discover I didn't know enough Star Trek to spot the reference even when it's been admitted. All those countless hours watching, and I seem to have learned nothing.... 2 minutes later I now know about **Amok Time** :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That's my good deed for the day, then.  My work here is done.

Answer (score 1):

It's often the case that an encoded file (compressed/encrypted, for example), might be decompressed/decrypted several times. Or the machine doing the encoding may be more powerful than the machine which will decode it later.

Therefore a lot of software designed to perform these tasks may spend more time (computing power) on the *encoding* than on the *decoding*. For example, internet streamed video (or broadcast digital TV) uses lengthy processor-intensive compression so cheap equipment can decode it fast enough to watch in real-time.

That's just background. In answer to the question, **decoding time** is the amount of elapsed time a computer takes to perform the decoding. "Time of decoding" simply refers to the general time-frame within which decoding is performed (as opposed to the **time of encoding** which is when it was encoded in the first place).

There is no meaningful difference between **data compression** and **compression of data**, except that we normally use the former.

Finally, we speak of **decoding time**, rather than **decoding's time** because we're using the word *decode* in an 'adjectival' mode to specify the type of time we're talking about, rather than as a noun to specify the name of the process taking place during that time. Also because it's a technical term, and techies in general don't like to waste even a single apostrophe or letter **s**.

Answer (score 1):

To your question of  "why isn't it 'decoding's time', but 'decoding time'?": It is not that the time *belongs to* decoding, but rather that is the the time *associated with* decoding. The "'s" usually indicates possession, as does "of", but "of" has many other meanings, "associated with" being one of them.

Comment: I disagree. Britain's climate doesn't *belong* to Britain - it's *associated with* it. Just because **'s** normally indicates ownership doesn't mean it always and only means exactly that.

Comment: Thanks, @FumbleFingers, I added "usually" to that statement. A moment's thought would have given me at least one counterexample like yours.

Comment: Well you've got more upvotes than me, even though I answered all three of OP's questions and you only addressed one. So I guess I have to accept the democratic process, though I'm not really convinced. :)

Comment: Two days' time, a day's work, the sun's rays...

Answer (score 0):

"decoding time" would usually mean *elapsed time* spent decoding the signal.

"time of decoding" could be *elapsed time*, but to me it suggests the <strike>absolute</strike> wall-clock time at which decoding took place.

"time spent decoding" and "timestamp of decoding" would both be unambiguous and one of these should be preferred.

Comment: I'd be astonished if any native English speaker who knew what we're talking about here ever used "time of decoding" to mean the amount of elapsed time. In my experience, "time of decoding" is almost always always used in a context where it's being contrasted with "time of encoding" because programmers don't mind spending more of *their* time making sure the latter is done as well as possible, so decoding can be as qui9ck and easy as possible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your comment seems to use "time of decoding" in exactly that way you say it never would be.  Fact is, both phrases are ambiguous, although usage is skewed.

Answer (score 0):

For the first pair, both statements can have multiple interpretations:

"decoding time" - It is now decoding time. (It is time to perform the decoding.)
                - What was the decoding time? (How long did the decoding take?)

"time of decoding" suffers from precisely the same ambiguity.

In general both refer to "how long did the decoding take", with "time of decoding" being more ambiguous.