# «'s» or «of the» which one should I use?

Tags: possessive-s-vs-of

I want to know if «'s» sounds more natural than «of the...». E.g.:

'My computer's keyboard' or 'The keyboard of my computer'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not about "sounding natural" -- I think this point has been dealt with earlier on these pages. See previous posts.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/apostrophe-s-vs-of

Comment: By the way, were you using the keyboard of *my* computer?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience as an Englishman the use of "The keyboard of my computer" or "The score of my team" is very rare and it is much more natural to say "My computer's keyboard" or "My team's score".

There is a side issue with your example that because a keyboard is so commonly part of a computer it would also be quite rare to say "My computer's keyboard" and most people would say "My keyboard".

Comment: Unless, of course, there's a need to distinguish it from some other keyboard.  (“My keyboard broke.”
“Your piano keyboard?”
“No, my computer's keyboard.”)