# Saturday's class vs saturday class

Tags: grammar, possessives

everyone!
I have a doubt about it:

saturday's class x saturday class

Which one is correct? I always get confused to know when I use 's when it comes to therms like these ones, when there isn't a human's name involved in the sentence like "Robert's car" etc. 
Can someone give me an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [Apostrophe-“s” vs “of ”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/apostrophe-s-vs-of)

Comment: [This](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine) can be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the word "Saturday" is always capitalized.  Secondly, your question depends on usage.  I would write "I didn't see you in Saturday's class,"  and I would write "Please note in the syllabus that there is a Saturday class in the third week."

Comment: Do you have any reason why you put the article in "a Saturday class" and didn't in "Saturday's class"?

Comment: @Rathony...besides the reason that it is the correct way to phrase such a sentence, and leaving "a" out of the second example or including it in the first would be ungrammatical?  Consider another sentence:  "It was five o'clock on Saturday."  v.s "It was five o'clock on a Saturday."  The two sentences connote different things.  The first names a specific Saturday, the second names the notion of or concept of Saturday.

Comment: The noun for which the article is used (or required) is not "Saturday" but "class".

Comment: indeed it is! Do you disagree with it?

Comment: My disagreeing with your answer doesn't matter. It would be nicer if you could include your reference/research for the answer.