# In the name of God vs In God's name

Tags: writing-style

In some pieces of writing it is needed to begin with the name of God; usually centered on top.

Is there any difference between the functionality of "`In the name of God`" and "`In God's name`"?

Please, bring suitable (and, if possible, academic) reference.

Thank you all, so much...

Comment: This may be a better question for the English Language Stack.

Comment: Please, bring suitable sentence (and, if possible, context) as an example of the way you wish to use this. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can one explain the different distributions of the Saxon and the analytic (Norman) (periphrastic, 'of') genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/can-one-explain-the-different-distributions-of-the-saxon-and-the-analytic-norma). Both are used; the Saxon genitive hints more at intimacy (more often used for persons) but may thus be closer to blasphemy. The periphrastic construction is more formal, and has more gravitas. Cadence value is opinion-based.

Comment: @Greybeard .  suppose, I need to write it on the top of a job resume`. thanks!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , That was a real HELP. Thank you my Friend . . .

Comment: 'I need to write it on the top of a job resume' That's _some_ referee.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not. It's there to show that the writer begs allowance and help from God to begin some issue; writing, in the case.

Comment: That would be a precising usage, off-topic on ELU. Standard English usages of the prepositional phrase can be looked up; there are strong connotations of 'the evils perpetrated _in the n/Name of God_ (by especially some people / groups claiming to be Christian)'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , the accepted answer has put the issue under the spotlight . . .

Comment: That's just two additions to the tens of thousands already on the internet. Few connected directly to job resumes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , You are completely right. But it's a kind of clearing . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the desired "Academic reference," scholar.google.com will provide a ranking of the academic books and papers, based on how many other papers cite the given paper.

## In the name of God

The search [In the name of God](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C34&q=%22In%20the%20name%20of%20God%22&btnG=) yielded about 53,200 results.

## In God's name

The search [In God's name](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C34&q=%22In%20God%27s%20name%22&btnG=) yielded about 13,900 results.

Papers and books from either alternative deal with religious violence or corruption.

### You pays your money and you takes your choice

Without more context, perhaps the OP should guess as to which alternative is more closely aligned with his or her thesis.

Answer (score 1):

"In the name of God" is more formal (by virtue of its being somewhat old-fashioned) than "In God's name".