# Is this genitive correct? “... the sustainability performance of firms”

Tags: apostrophe, of-genitive

I read the following sentence and I was wondering if this is correct:

"Society and activist, non-governmental organizations monitor **the sustainability performance of firms**."

Or is **"monitor
 firms' sustainability performance"** preferable, using the Saxon genitive?

Thank you!

Comment: _The firm's_ is singular and indicates one specific firm, not all firms. Since the difference between singular and plural would depend on apostrophe placement with a preposed genitive, I'd go with _of_ because it doesn't require silent letters.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was my mistake. It is supposed to be "monitor firms' sustainability performance" due to the plural form. Is the first sentence grammatically wrong? What´s about the sentence mentioned here.

Comment: This is a good place **not** to use the apostrophe genitive. If anything, the first sentence is more grammatical. Some days I just want to line up all English textbook writers and shoot them.

Comment: @John Lawler Along with all the greengrocers? Actually, they're key workers, so I'd oppose this step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can one explain the different distributions of the Saxon and the analytic (Norman) (periphrastic, 'of') genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/can-one-explain-the-different-distributions-of-the-saxon-and-the-analytic-norma) Here, 'monitor the sustainability performance of firms' sounds far better than 'monitor firms' sustainability performance' partly because it just sounds better, but partly because the periphrastic (of-) genitive adds gravitas: the formal, professional touch. The Saxon genitive hints at familiarity, intimacy.