# What is this kind of "___ of ___" syntax called?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'm wondering what the technical term is for this kind of syntax:

"It is not wrong to say that the use of dairy in cooking results from marketing."

Often I see it in sentences like "the idea of____ stems from X," or "the point of ___ reminds us to..."

Or more generally, "the ___ of _____ (verb)..."

What is this called? Thank you!

Comment: Could you give some more examples? This looks like every sentence with two nouns in it.

Comment: With rephrasings (not always 'perfect synonyms') such as say _a day's work / the work of a day_, the two forms are known as the Saxon genitive, and the Norman (or analytic) ('periphrastic _of_') genitive, respectively. No 'ownership' need be involved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can one explain the different distributions of the Saxon and the analytic (Norman) (periphrastic, 'of') genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/can-one-explain-the-different-distributions-of-the-saxon-and-the-analytic-norma) With rephrasings (not always 'perfect synonyms') such as say _a day's work / the work of a day_, the two forms are known as the Saxon genitive, and the Norman (or analytic) ('periphrastic of') genitive, respectively. No 'ownership' need be involved. // Partitives look identical (_a slice of cake_), as do ...

Comment: pseudo-partitives (_a box of chocolates, a can of lemonade_).

Answer (score 2):

The *noun of noun* construction is called a partitive when used to refer to parts of wholes. For example: *a slice of bread, a majority of the people*. I am not aware of a term that covers all such specific *noun of noun* constructions, including the examples you give.

A general term, however, is *collocation*. So the preposition *of* collocates with the nouns *idea, use* and *point*, as in your examples. Other *noun + of* collocations include: *cause of, love of, fear of, risk of*.

Other nouns collocate with different prepositions: *cure for, case for, rise in, belief in, information on, report on*, etc.

There are more [noun+preposition collocations](https://7esl.com/noun-preposition-collocations) on the excellent 7ESL site.