# Difference between "Education Institute" & "Institute of Education"?

Tags: differences, possessives, attributive-nouns

Also, what is this property called? **X Y** versus **Y of X.**

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30577/which-one-is-correct-teacher-of-english-or-english-teacher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Education Institute* modifies the head noun *institute* with a [**noun adjunct,**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) also called an **attributive noun** or sometimes an **adjectival noun.** More simply, it is a noun used as an adjective.

*Institute of Education* modifies it with a [**genitive construction**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_construction). Genitives express a relationship between nouns, usually possession, but in this case the relationship is one of composition (the nature of the institute).

Hypothetically, noun adjuncts are less restrictive about the kinds of relationships they can express than genitives are, but in practice, **X Y** and **Y of X** are often interchangeable, as in this example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe that when you say *Education Institute* you are referring to institutes regarding education in general.

When you say *Institute of Education* you are referring to that specific institute.

Sorry if this explanation sounds a bit vague, it's hard to bring it using solid words :)

Comment: It's not the grammar that suggests general versus specific, but rather the capitalization, which marks both phrases as proper nouns.

Answer (score -2):

"Education institute" is an institute or school organization that provides education that provides educational service to students, for example any online education service. "Institute of education" is physical and provides education like school college or university

Comment: This is an interesting view, but you would need to provide some evidence that an institute of education is always physical. There seems to be no linguistic reason for that interpretation.