# "I am a teacher of English." or "I am a teacher in English." Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

Please say which of the following is correct.

> I am a teacher of English.
> I am a teacher in English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which one is correct? "A teacher of English" or "An English teacher"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30577/which-one-is-correct-a-teacher-of-english-or-an-english-teacher)

Answer (score 3):

A teacher *of* English teaches the English language as a subject. A teacher *in* English uses the English language as the medium in which to teach their subject. For instance there might be a physics teacher who teaches *in* English and students who did not understand English would not learn much physics ftom them.

To some extent all teachers *of* English do teach *in* English becsuse they have to but someone who taught English as a foreign language *in* English would not use, maybe would not know, the native language(s) of their student(s). English classes for immigrants often have to be taught *in* English because the students have different native languages. A teacher *of* English in a French school, however, would normally teach partly *in* French.

Comment: A 'teacher in English' is unidiomatic. Even 'teacher of English' is fairly rare compared with 'English teacher'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'll agree that "a teacher in English" is very rare but the sentence "All classes are taught in English/French/Chinese/Welsh etc" are quite common, a teacher of one of those classes would be "a teacher _in_ English/French/Chinese/Welsh etc".